# Showing a Dialog onCompleted doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to show a `Dialog` `onCompleted` under some condition (handling this condition omitted here - a simple `if` clause)

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: appWindow

    width: 480
    height: 640
    visible: true


    StackView
    {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        // Implements back key navigation
        focus: true

        initialItem: Item
        {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            Button { onClicked: dialog.open() }
            // ...
            Component.onCompleted: dialog.open()
        }
    }

    MyDialog {id: dialog }
}
```

MyDialog.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Dialog
{
    id: root

    title: "MyDialog"
    standardButtons: Qt.NoButton

    ColumnLayout
    {
        id: column
        width: parent ? parent.width : 200
        Label { text: "hello world"; Layout.fillWidth: true }
    }
}
```

When I launch my app, the screen is dimmed, and the `Dialog`'s shade appears, as though the dialog had `width == 0`.

Sometimes (rarely) the dialog shows correctly.

If I comment out the `Component.onCompleted` line and launch the dialog using the `Button`, it is displayed correctly.

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Qt 5.5 for Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the dialog doesn't work correctly if it's opened before the window has a sane geometry.

A safe option is to use the `onWidthChanged` signal

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: appWindow

    width: 480
    height: 640
    visible: true


    StackView
    {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        // Implements back key navigation
        focus: true

        initialItem: Item
        {
            property bool firstTime: true
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            // ...
            // width may be called multiple times
            onWidthChanged: if (firstTime) {firstTime = true; dialog.open()}
        }
    }

    MyDialog {id: dialog }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer to official documentation about [Dialog QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html#details), there you can find next:

> **Note:** do not attempt to bind the width or height of the dialog to the
>   width or height of its content, because Dialog already tries to size
>   itself to the content. If your goal is to change or eliminate the
>   margins, you must override contentItem. If your goal is simply to show
>   a window (whether modal or not), and your platform supports it, it is
>   simpler to use Window instead.

So, in your case, it will be better somehow set width of your inner element implicitly. Another quick solution is to add (for example) `Rectangle` element with given width as only one inner root element of your Dialog. Rest of elements you can place inside this `Rectangle`.

Comment: The problem appears only when I launch the dialog `onCompleted` (see the updated OP). Qt examples themselves suggest setting `width` to `parent.width`, see 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickdialogs-systemdialogs-customdialogs-qml.html

Comment: First, you are right -- it is interesting point in original examples. Second, it's a QML -> IMO, never can be sure for 100%. Here is cite from documentation to (Component)[http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html]: 
>The corresponding handler is `onCompleted`. It can be declared on any object. The order of running the `onCompleted` handlers is **undefined**.
Just a note for testing -- try to trigger `dialog.open()` on your StackedView `depth` change.

Comment: Yes, it was the case. I posted one solution I worked out. Using the `Stack.status` attach property is even more efficient than using `depth`. If you have a better idea, please post it.

Comment: No, I have no better idea. Seems like your way to solve it is ok.

Comment: Using `Stack.status` does not always work. I've just found it out :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting another answer because it is another approach. I remembered how I implemented it on some old project. AFAIK, For now it is the best way. *I would be really happy if anyone gave better solution*.

You need to add one intermediary element like [`Timer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html). This timer (`tm` in code below) must have small interval (like 30ms) and need to be started on your desired event -- `Component.onCompleted`. Put your action in `onTriggered` of this timer.

Here is code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Timer {
        id: tm
        interval: 30
        onTriggered: dialog.open()
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        // Implements back key navigation
        focus: true
        initialItem: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.heonTriggeredight
            Button { onClicked: dialog.open() }
            Component.onCompleted: tm.start()
        }
    }

    MyDialog { id: dialog }
}
```